# Google Analytics API wrongly sorts social acquisitions into referrals when using ga:medium dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This problem is documented in the issues for Google Analytics [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=654&can=1&q=social&sort=-type&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&). Digging deeper, the problem seems to be with Google incorrectly labeling obvious social domains as referrals.

Looking at [this](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-08-08&end-date=2015-09-07&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AsourceMedium&sort=-ga%3Asessions) query, one can see that obvious social sources such as facebook.com are being listed as referrals. In fact, the only domains which Google seems to correctly recognize as social are twitter.com and linkedin.com (which they don't even recognize all of -- linkedin.com appears twice on that list for me and only one is correctly labeled as social).

The logged issue on code.google.com doesn't seem to be getting much attention, so I'm asking if anyone has encountered this issue and has a way around it (short of using ga:sourceMedium and manually checking each source to see if it's one of the dozens that Google misses).